# Make a matrix from submatrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, submatrix

I need to make a matrix in `R` with its elements are from matrices I defined before.
For example, I have 4 matrices,

```
w <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)
x <- matrix(c(5,6,7,8),2,2)
y <- matrix(c(9,10,11,12),2,2)
z <- matrix(c(13,14,15,16),2,2)
```

Then, the new matrix should be a `4X4` matrix with `w` is an `[1:2,1:2]` element, `x` is an `[1:2,3:4]` element, `y` is an `[3:4,1:2]` element, and `z` is an `[3:4,3:4]` element.

How can I do that quickly?

Comment: `rbind( cbind(w,x), cbind(y,z) )` as a manual version of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create an `array` and then loop through the third dimension, and `rbind` it.

```
ar1 <- array(c(w, x, y,z), dim=c(2, 4,2))
do.call(rbind,lapply(seq(dim(ar1)[3]), function(i) ar1[,,i]))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    3    5    7
#[2,]    2    4    6    8
#[3,]    9   11   13   15
#[4,]   10   12   14   16
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned in the comments

```
apply(array(c(w,x,y,z), dim=c(2,4,2)), 2, I)
```

where `I` stands for `inhibit interpretation` or use `identity` in place of `I`

Comment: `apply(ar1,2,identity)` will also get you there - or `apply(array(c(w,x,y,z), dim=c(2,4,2)), 2, identity)` all in one go

Comment: What is dim=c(2,4,2) mean?

Comment: @YohanesEkiApriliawan  It is the dimension attributes we specify for the 3d array ie.

Comment: `I` doesn't stand for `identity` - it probably stands for `inhibit interpretation` as per the help file at `?I`